bone copy a mesh
I have problem with bone copy a mesh in deformed state I had applied solidified before Idk if this is the cause

edit : I know the problem now it because of solidified I sim new sock and it work no problem now

hello you need to correct the weight paint or mask the parent that you don't want to protude
